# overlap div elements with box-shadow property

Tags: html, css

When I launch the scroll, I add a class to the div-operator, causing it to display a box-shadow at the top of the div-operator.

But according to the image below, the input, select, etc ... elements are above the shadow.

How do I make the top shadow overlap the elements that are inside the div-operator while being rolled up?

```js
$('#div-operador"').scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 1) {
 $('#div-operador').addClass('shadow');
    }
    else {
        $('#div-operador').removeClass('shadow');
    }
});
```

```css
#div-operador {
   padding-top: 5px;
   overflow: auto;
   width: auto;
   max-height: 205px;
   height: 205px;
}
.shadow {
   box-shadow: inset 0 7px 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   z-index:5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-xs-8">
   <div id="div-operador" class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel-perfil">Perfil</label>
                  <select id="sel-perfil" class="form-control input-sm form-md-3" name="perfil"  title="Perfil" autocomplete="off" required >
                      <option>Perfil</option>
                  </select>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel-nivel">Nível</label>
                  <select id="sel-nivel" class="form-control input-sm form-md-3" name="nivel"  title="nivel" autocomplete="off" required >
                      <option>Perfil</option>
                  </select>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel-email">email</label>
                  <input type="text" id="txt-email" class="form-control input-sm form-md-3" name="email" autocomplete="off" required />
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="txt-login">login</label>
                  <input type="text" id="txt-login" class="form-control input-sm form-md-3" name="login" autocomplete="off" required />
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Provide a code snippet that reproduce the issue. The one available generates an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks.

I managed to solve it here in the SO in Portuguese [on here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361405/sobrepor-elementos-da-div-com-a-propriedade-box-shadow/361457?noredirect=1#comment722068_361457)